# How to get a depth map from a Kinect 360 depth sensor?

Tags: image-processing, sensor

I'm trying to understand how Kinect 360 depth sensor works. At the moment, I know that this sensor is composed by an infrared pattern generator and a infrared camera. IR camera gets the pattern generated from the IR emitter, and using math it calculates a depth value for each pixel. The process of emitting a light in a pattern is called Structured Light. So the question is, I don't really understand how an IR image is transformed into a depth map.

I read some documents, like [Accuracy and Resolution of Kinect Depth Data for Indoor Mapping Applications](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/2/1437/htm), but I don't really understand how it works. I would appreciate any help. I have a Kinect 360, so I could generate some images if it helps.

Comment: *Structure light* is just the *projection of the grid* (or whatever structured pattern), not the inference of depth from its observation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.